# Google Maps React - No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-maps, react-wrapper

I'm getting this error when trying to run my app

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ map: google.maps.Map | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<unknown> & Attributes'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'map' does not exist in type 'Partial<unknown> & Attributes'.
    60 |                        {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    61 |                                if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
  > 62 |                                        return React.cloneElement(child, { map });
       |                                                                           ^^^
    63 |                                }
    64 |                        })}
    65 |                </>
```

In my package.json I have installed the `"@types/google.maps": "^3.49.2"` and `"@types/google.maps": "^3.49.2"`

The map itself was working just right, but then this happened.
I don't know where this error is coming from, please help.

The map component:

```
const MapComponent = ({ children, style, zoom = 8, lat, lng }: MapProps) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map>();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current && !map) {
            setMap(
                new window.google.maps.Map(ref.current, {
                    zoom,
                    center: {
                        lat,
                        lng,
                    },
                })
            );
        }
    }, [ref, map]);

    return (
        <>
            <div ref={ref} style={style} />
            {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
                if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
                    return React.cloneElement(child, { map });
                }
            })}
        </>
    );
};

const Map = ({
    className = '',
    height = 22,
    zoom = 8,
    latitude = 30,
    longitude = -180,
    markerLat,
    markerLng,
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <div
            data-testid="contact-card"
            className={`w-fill rounded-lg border border-gray-border ${className}`}
            style={{ height: `${height}rem` }}
        >
            <Wrapper apiKey={EnvironmentVariables.GOOGLE_MAPS} render={render}>
                <MapComponent
                    style={{ flexGrow: '1', height: '100%' }}
                    lat={latitude}
                    lng={longitude}
                    zoom={zoom}
                >
                    {markerLat && markerLng && (
                        <Marker position={{ lat: markerLat, lng: markerLng }} />
                    )}
                </MapComponent>
            </Wrapper>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Stackoverflow doesnt allow me to show the full code due to the size of the code. But [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/github/googlemaps/js-samples/tree/sample-react-map) is an example of I did it

Comment: Please show how you use the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what solved my problem was changing the map useState type and returning the React.cloneElement(child) as a React element.

```
    const [map, setMap] = useState<google.maps.Map & Partial<unknown>>();
```

And on the MapComponent return ...

```
            {React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
                if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
                    return React.cloneElement(child as React.ReactElement<any>, { map });
                }
            })}
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing exactly same thing, just figure it out five minutes ago.

Basically I follow [doc from google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/react-map), of course it doesn't work, I change declaration of MapProps to this

```
interface MapProps extends google.maps.MapOptions {
    style: { [key: string]: string };
    onClick?: (e: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) => void;
    onIdle?: (map: google.maps.Map) => void;
    children?: React.ReactElement<google.maps.MarkerOptions>;
}
```

with code above, type of `cloneElement` will change from `undefined` to `google.maps.MarkerOptions`, the reason I did this is the second parameter of `cloneElement` is `Partial`, and we want to change the map parameter of `MarkerOptions`.

if the there will be single or multiple child, can try this

```
children?: React.ReactElement<google.maps.MarkerOptions>[] | React.ReactElement<google.maps.MarkerOptions>
```